# PHP function with SQL query does not return a value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I want to create a function in  PHP that will return the values of an SQL query in an array.
The SQL code in the function works and i can display the values.

But when i want to use it in an function, it will not work. What is the error in my syntax?

```
function frequenz_suchen_datum_zeit($fdatum_von = "2000-01-01", $fdatum_bis = "2020-01-01", $fuhrzeit_von = "00:00:00", $fuhrzeit_bis = "23:59:59") {
$abfrage = $pdo->query("SELECT
                SUM(hg_ger_b) as hg_ger_b,
                SUM(hg_ger_v) as hg_ger_v,
                SUM(hg_zub_b) as hg_zub_b,
                SUM(hg_zub_v) as hg_zub_v,
                SUM(hg_ers_b) as hg_ers_b,
                SUM(hg_ers_v) as hg_ers_v,
                SUM(hg_rep) as hg_rep,
                SUM(pr_ger_b) as pr_ger_b,
                SUM(pr_ger_v) as pr_ger_v,
                SUM(pr_zub_b) as pr_zub_b,
                SUM(pr_zub_v) as pr_zub_v,
                SUM(pr_ers_b) as pr_ers_b,
                SUM(pr_ers_v) as pr_ers_v,
                SUM(pr_rep) as pr_rep,
                SUM(so_ser) as so_ser, 
                SUM(so_mie) as so_mie,
                SUM(so_was) as so_was,
                SUM(so_wer) as so_wer,
                SUM(so_web) as so_web
                FROM frequenz WHERE datum BETWEEN '".$fdatum_von."' AND '".$fdatum_bis."' AND uhrzeit BETWEEN '".$fuhrzeit_von."' AND '".$fuhrzeit_bis."'")->fetch();

return abfrage;
}

$test = frequenz_suchen_datum_zeit();
echo $test [hg_ger_b];
```

Comment: Please use bind variables and a prepared statement.

Comment: "no working" doesn't help us. Are you getting an error? Does the function return anything? Do you have full error handing turned on to see any possible problem?

Comment: i become an empty site.
When I use the SQL Code without the function, i can display the array.

Comment: This kind of problem is highly symptomatic of poor schema design.

Comment: "empty site" - If you mean a blank page, there is likely a fatal error. Always when developing and testing code, at the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.  This line has an unquoted array key: `echo $test [hg_ger_b];` should be as echo `$test['hg_ger_b'];`

Comment: I _think_ the unquoted value still issues a warning rather than a fatal error.

Comment: Queries like this are what happen when you violate the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As `$pdo` is unknown inside the function it will not work.

Quick ugly fix: add as first line of the function:

```
global $pdo;
```

The problem is that the `$pdo` object is out of scope. Please see this documentation resource: https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.variables.scope.php

Here is the full code including the global:

```
function frequenz_suchen_datum_zeit($fdatum_von = "2000-01-01", $fdatum_bis = "2020-01-01", $fuhrzeit_von = "00:00:00", $fuhrzeit_bis = "23:59:59") {

global $pdo;    
$abfrage = $pdo->query("SELECT
                    SUM(hg_ger_b) as hg_ger_b,
                    SUM(hg_ger_v) as hg_ger_v,
                    SUM(hg_zub_b) as hg_zub_b,
                    SUM(hg_zub_v) as hg_zub_v,
                    SUM(hg_ers_b) as hg_ers_b,
                    SUM(hg_ers_v) as hg_ers_v,
                    SUM(hg_rep) as hg_rep,
                    SUM(pr_ger_b) as pr_ger_b,
                    SUM(pr_ger_v) as pr_ger_v,
                    SUM(pr_zub_b) as pr_zub_b,
                    SUM(pr_zub_v) as pr_zub_v,
                    SUM(pr_ers_b) as pr_ers_b,
                    SUM(pr_ers_v) as pr_ers_v,
                    SUM(pr_rep) as pr_rep,
                    SUM(so_ser) as so_ser, 
                    SUM(so_mie) as so_mie,
                    SUM(so_was) as so_was,
                    SUM(so_wer) as so_wer,
                    SUM(so_web) as so_web
                    FROM frequenz WHERE datum BETWEEN '".$fdatum_von."' AND '".$fdatum_bis."' AND uhrzeit BETWEEN '".$fuhrzeit_von."' AND '".$fuhrzeit_bis."'")->fetch();
    
    return abfrage;
    }
    
    $test = frequenz_suchen_datum_zeit();
    echo $test [hg_ger_b];
```